# How to reuse tooltip DOM across fields, for angular form validation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form in my angular template, and I can define a  that shows up when an input field has an error. Like this:

```
<input ng-model="myField" type="email" ng-minlength="8" required>
```

And then to show the tooltip:

```
<div class="error toolTip" ng-show="userForm.myField.error">Please enter a value</div>
```

This works.

However, I have multiple fields on the page and I want to re-use the tooltip DOM instead of writing multiple tooltip s for each field. Whats the best way to achive this while still taking advantage of angular's validation?

Here's a jquery version of what I am trying to achieve (reuse tooltip div): http://jsfiddle.net/mw6t82ae/1/

Answer (score 0):

If the tooltip appears in only one area, you could write a function that cycles through your form and sees if any field is in the error state. If it is, it returns true, and you can call this function in your `ng-show` attribute,

Comment: But then that function would return true if ANY of the fields have an error. I want the tooptip to be positioned near the respective field, and have innerHTML relevant to that field and what type of error that field has. So the function needs to know WHICH element has an error and WHY.

Comment: I'm confused. Didn't you say you wanted to sue the same markup? If you are writing a separate `div` for each field, why not just refer to that field in the `ng-show` attribute?

Comment: I don't want to write a separate div for each field. I want one global "tooltip" div, that gets positioned near the respective field that has an error when the field is focused. If I go with multiple <div>s then the answer is quite straightforward, but I was wondering if there's a way to do it with a single tooltip div.

Comment: Here's a jquery version of what I am trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/mw6t82ae/1/